# JSON control if @currentfield is empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I'm using JSON to format a hyperlink column in SharePoint online. If the column @currentfield isn't filled in, there shouldn't be a link. Can anyone help me?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://contoso.sharepoint.com/w' + @currentField"

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using a style tag with a conditional, see below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='https://contoso.sharepoint.com/w' + @currentField"
  "style": {
    "display": "=if(@currentField!='', 'block','none !important')",
  }
}
```

Though personally, I like a good link icon, so I format mine like so:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "iconName": "Link",
        "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
        "href": "=if(@currentField!='',@currentField,''"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if(@currentField!='', 'block','none !important')",
        "padding-left": "40px"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution!
Its working great for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the way to format the field as a hyperlink if it is not empty only.

The way I can think of implementing this requirement is to turn the empty field to a link which is used to refresh the page.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "=if(@currentField!='','_blank', '_self')",
    "href": "=if(@currentField!='','https://testlz.sharepoint.com/sites/' + @currentField, '')"
  }
}
```

[JSON formatting in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: any progress on this? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with column formatting.