# Column Formatting to Show a Hyperlink or just Text Based on 3rd Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

PrimaryLink is to display a hyperlink based on the other 2 fields

PrimaryName
PrimaryURL
PrimaryLink

JSON for Column Formatting

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "[$PrimaryName]",
   "attributes": {
   "target": "_blank",
   "href": "[$PrimaryURL]"
    }
}
```

So if I enter a PrimaryName and a PrimaryURL, it would display the PrimaryName as a hyperlink in PrimaryLink to what was set in PrimaryURL.  If I only put a PrimaryName in, it still displays a hyperlink that goes to the /list/AllItems.aspx

Is there a way where if I don't populate PrimaryURL, that it can only display PrimaryName text and no hyperlink?

Tried this from a post recommended in comments, but it leaves the whole column empty.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "[$PrimaryName]",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$PrimaryURL]"
  }
    "style":{
        "display": "=if([$PrimaryURL]!='', 'block', 'none !important')"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON control if @currentfield is empty](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249966/json-control-if-currentfield-is-empty)

Comment: html is no longer permissable in calculated columns - I notice you have used a <a href>

Comment: You don't need a calculated column here.  You cannot create an anchor tag through calculated formulas any way.  Use [the answer to this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249966/json-control-if-currentfield-is-empty) in your column formatting for your PrimaryName field to render conditionally based on PrimaryURL.

Comment: Yes, the calculated column was leftover from the SP2013 on-prem solution.  I also tried adding a text column and used my same JSON and it displays all hyperlinks, but wouldn't contain the proper link if I put in a PrimaryURL.  So given that, I just left it as is.

Comment: I had tried the link that yalls have suggested as well.  If I leave my href section and then add this, PrimaryLink is just empty.   `"style": {
    "display": "=if([$PrimaryURL]!='', 'block','none !important')",
  }`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not setting `PrimaryURL` column as a **Required** field? Also, try my answer given below. it should work for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes, because they do not put that value in right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below JSON Code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "[$PrimaryName]",
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$PrimaryURL] != '', 'none', 'block')"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "[$PrimaryName]",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "[$PrimaryURL]"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$PrimaryURL] != '', 'block', 'none')"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**official documentation**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Column formatting - Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples)

**Update from Comments**:

1. In order to reference a column in JSON formatting it should be included in list view.
2. If you are adding the URL in `PrimaryLink` column and then adding the JSON in `PrimaryName` column then try below JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "txtContent": "@currentField",
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$PrimaryLink] != '', 'none', 'block')"
            }
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "@currentField",
            "attributes": {
                "target": "_blank",
                "href": "[$PrimaryLink]"
            },
            "style": {
                "display": "=if([$PrimaryLink] != '', 'block', 'none')"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!  That worked a treat.  So as I was doing a lot of testing, I was finding good resources scarce.  Do you have some good places/sites/?? where I can improve my JSON?

Comment: Check the documentation link in updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, if I hide the PrimaryURL from view, the PrimaryName and PrimaryLink goes empty.  Does that happen to you?  Surely that can't be by design because that would defeat the purpose of views.

Comment: I think in order the JSON formatting to work, your column should be in the list view. I will check it tomorrow on my machine and let you know.

Comment: I tried to make the solution have less variables/columns, so tried to do PrimaryName and PrimaryLink.  If I put in the URL in PrmaryLink and then put the JSON in PrimaryName, it's curious that when I refresh the page, it doesn't even display the text without the hyperlink.

Comment: Check my updated answer and use the JSON provided in update section.